# Making my own admin panel for Wordpress

Tags: php

So I'm making a customer service portal using Wordpress, and it's been pretty good so far. To preface, I have a few relevant custom fields.

Customers have "isSalesperson" == No. Salespeople have "isSalesperson" == Yes. Then a salesperson has a "salespersonID" equivalent to a number. All of their customers have a salespersonID equivalent to that same number. There's also "super" which means you can see all customers. I want to only list the clients that have the same salespersonID as the salesperson when they are looking at this page.

```
$admin = wp_get_current_user();
$salespersonID = $admin->salespersonID;

if($salespersonID != "Super"){  
    $meta_query_args = array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key'     => 'salespersonID',
            'value'   => $salespersonID,
        )
    );
}
else
{
    $meta_query_args = array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key'     => 'salespersonID',
            'value'   => 0,
            'compare' => '!=',
        )
    );
}  

$meta_query = new WP_Meta_Query( $meta_query_args );
$args = array(
    'meta_key'     => 'companyname',
    'orderby'      => 'meta_value',
    'order'        => 'ASC',
    'meta_query'   => $meta_query,
);

$users = get_users($args);
foreach ( $users as $user ) {
  if($user->isSalesperson == "No"){
    echo '<option>' . $user->companyname . '</option>';
  }
}
```

My issue is that I'm not sure how to use the WP_Meta_Query in order to select only the users that meet the criteria of their salespersonID being equivalent to the current logged-in user's salespersonID. Currently, the code runs without error but doesn't actually do what I want. It simply shows all of the results.

Comment: Why not use custom roles for your salesperson instead of that meta field hack?

Comment: Wouldn't that still give me a similar issue? I've already implemented it this way but for future role types I'll certainly use a custom role.